# Get an Enterprise Edition of salesforce?

Tags: enterprise, product

Please provide me a link for purchasing enterprise edition of salesforce.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

it's not shopping cart like thing. you should use [contact us](http://www.salesforce.com/in/crm/editions-pricing-service.jsp?d=70130000000tS0K&internal=true) or call help line @ 000 800 001 6000

Comment: Hello Krish , Check this link http://www.salesforce.com/in/crm/editions-pricing-service.jsp and for enable you can contact Salesforce team.  Information for contact are in link above.